# Is there a way to get your friends events with Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, fbconnect

Can this be accomplished and what permissions do I need for this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found it, I need a friends_events permission and https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/events?access_token={acces_token} link